# CNTK 2.0 beta 7 installation error - install.ps1 not digitally signed

Tags: cntk

I downloaded cntk 2.0 beta 7. when executing .\install.ps1, got this error for install.ps1 not digitally signed:

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:> cd .\local\cntk\Scripts\install\windows\
PS C:\local\cntk\Scripts\install\windows> .\install.ps1
.\install.ps1 : File C:\local\cntk\Scripts\install\windows\install.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file
C:\local\cntk\Scripts\install\windows\install.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current
system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\install.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

---

and if I start powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted
install.ps1 is able to run but nothing got installed, here is the output:

```
This script will setup the CNTK prequisites and the CNTK Python environment onto the machine.
More help is given by calling 'get-help .\install.ps1' in your powershell environment.

The script will analyse your machine and will determine which components are required.
The required components will be downloaded in [C:\local\cntk\Scripts\install\windows\InstallCache]
Repeated operation of this script will reuse already downloaded components.

 - If required VS2012 Runtime and VS2013 Runtime will be installed
 - If required MSMPI will be installed
 - Anaconda3 will be installed into [C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64]
 - A CNTK-PY34 environment will be created or updated in [C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs]
 - CNTK will be installed or updated in the CNTK-PY34 environment


The parameter '-Execute' hasn't be supplied to the script.
The script will execute withouth making any actual changes to the machine.


1 - I agree and want to continue
Q - Quit the installation process

1
Determining Operations to perform. This will take a moment...

The following operations will be performed:
 * Install Anaconda3-4.1.10
 * Setup CNTK PythonEnvironment 3.4
 * Setup/Update CNTK Wheel
 * Create CNTKPY34 batch file

Do you want to continue? (y/n)
y
Performing download operations
Downloading [https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64.exe], please be patient....
 ** Running in DEMOMODE - no download performed
Download operations finished

Performing install operations
Installing Anaconda3-4.1.1. This will take several minutes. Please be patient ....
** Running in DEMOMODE - setting Exit Code **: 0
** Running in DEMOMODE - setting Exit Code **: 0
Setup/Update of CNTK Wheel environment. Please be patient....
** Running in DEMOMODE - setting Exit Code **: 0
Create-Batch [C:\local\cntk\scripts\cntkpy34.bat]:No-Execute flag. No file created
Install operations finished
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read the output or the documentation on the wiki!

"The parameter '-Execute' hasn't be supplied to the script. The script will execute withouth making any actual changes to the machine"

Run the script as `.\install.ps1 -Execute`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and used the sign-tool from Microsoft to digitally sign the files. After signing, *this* error vanished.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx

"SignTool is available as part of the Windows SDK ..."

Answer (score 0):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Just run this command 
Try this easy fix!